# ASP.NET MVC async await deadlock need ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

Will this cause a deadlock? I have read where adding .ConfigureAwait(false) is needed if the calling class uses ".Result", but does that apply here with controllers... any help is appreciated. I have a bunch of this type of "stuff" going on and deadlocks seem to be happening. The server actually shows 4 threads in a w3wp dump and a lot of requests "waiting", which causes a freeze where no connections can be made, then it unhangs and resumes. rinse and repeat. I cant figure it out.

This is an MVC controller:

```
public class DashboardController
{
    private readonly IVendorResource _vendorResource;

    public DashboardController(IVendorResource vendorResource)
    {
        _vendorResource = vendorResource;           
    }

    // GET: Dashboard
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var vendor = await _vendorResource.Get(1);

        vendor.ToDashboardViewModel();
        vendor.Emails = await _vendorResource.GetVendorEmails(1);

        var model = vendor.ToDashboardViewModel();
        model.PageTitle = "Dashboard";

        var vendorMetrics = await _vendorResource.GetVendorMetrics(1);
        model.VendorMetrics = vendorMetrics.ToVewModel();

        return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Index.cshtml", model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `.Result` anywhere?

Comment: no .Result anywhere.

Comment: @crizzwald, well, if it was a deadlock I don't think that it would _unhang_. `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is more complicated than just only to avoid deadlocks with `.Result`. [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx)'s a fine post that will help you understand it better. your code seems to be fine as for me. issue can be in your environment or in `IVendorResource` implementation.